# Running Hadoop on GPFS

Tags: hadoop

What other options does hadoop derive from the fs.default.name option?

I'm trying to get hadoop running over GPFS instead of HDFS. I have configured hadoop to use the libgpfs.so, libgpfshadoop.so, and hadoop-1.1.1-gpfs.jar libraries provided by IBM.
I'm running into trouble with the core-site.xml config (I suspect) and starting up the namenode. SSH is working and configured correctly.

Launching the namenode with:

```
sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config $CONFIG_DIR --script hdfs start namenode
```

results in:

```
014-12-05 14:55:50,819 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: fs.defaultFS is gpfs:///
2014-12-05 14:55:50,941 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-12-05 14:55:51,063 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI for NameNode address (check fs.defaultFS): gpfs:/// has no authority.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getRpcServerAddress(NameNode.java:464)
```

My core-site config:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hadoop</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>gpfs:///</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>fs.gpfs.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.gpfs.GlobalParallelFileSystem</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>gpfs.mount.dir</name>
        <value>/mnt/gpfs</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I think hadoop is expecting fs.default.name to contain an ip and port which it uses to propagate other config options, but since I am using GPFS, I don't need to.

A thought... Do I need to run a namenode if using GPFS? Can I just run hadoop with the jobtracker?